# Fisher Information of Logit Model is Nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics

Let $(Y_1,X_1)$, $\dots$, $(Y_n,X_n)$, $Y_i \in \{0,1\}$, $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be a random sample following the model $P_\theta(Y_i=1|X_i=x)=\Psi(\theta^Tx)$, where $\Psi(\theta)=1/(1+e^{-\theta})$. The conditional density of $Y_i$ is then $p_\theta(Y_i|X_i)=\Psi(\theta^TX_i)^{Y_i}(1-\Psi(\theta^TX_i))^{1-Y_i}$, and the Fisher information is $I_\theta=E(\dfrac{\Psi'(\theta^TX)^2}{\Psi(\theta^TX)(1-\Psi)(\theta^TX)}XX^T)$.

I want to show that $I_\theta$ is nonsingular. The proof I am looking at suggests that $I_\theta$ is nonsingular because it is continuous in $\theta$ and bounded below by a multiple of $E(XX^T)$. I am not sure how to show that it is bounded below by $E(XX^T)$, and I am not sure how to show that this would imply that it is nonsingular. Alternatively, I considered applying the theorem that a bounded linear operator $T$ between normed spaces is nonsingular if it is bounded below in the sense that for each $u$, $||Tu||\geq b||u||$ for some $b>0$. But it isn't clear to me how to find $b$.